# SCIKIT Learn multi-class error

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a script that successfully ran about a year ago which no longer runs.  I use pandas to process the data into this:

df_train

```
    dtu_docid                                    dtu_topic_split         y_train
0   2012-1553          [Energy Taxation, State & Local Taxation]         [3, 23]
2   2010-0227            [Quantitative Economics and Statistics]            [34]
3   2010-0215                     [International Taxation, Asia]         [0, 19]
```

and then use scikit as follows:

```
classifier = Pipeline([
    ('vectorizer', CountVectorizer(stop_words='english',
                                   ngram_range=(1,3),
                                   max_df = 1.0,
                                   min_df = 0.0,
                                   analyzer='word')),
    ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
    ('clf', OneVsRestClassifier(LinearSVC(verbose=1)))])


classifier.fit(df_train.dtu_content, df_train.y_train)
```

and now get an error that is driving me crazy:

```
ValueError: Expected array-like (array or non-string sequence), got 0 [3, 23]
2 [34]
3 [0, 19]
4 []
5 [3]
8 [8, 27]
9 [10]
11 [15]
12 [0, 7]
13 [1, 4]
14 [1, 4, 13] ... (truncated)
15 [11] ... (truncated)
```

It looks like there was a enhancement to the multiclass.py module about 9 months ago that causes additional checking, but I cannot figure our how to fix.  Anyone seen this before or have an ideas?

Comment: I have been working on this again this morning and found some cryptic notes in github about a possible fix.  It seems as if recent versions of either pandas or scikit broke something pretty important.  IMHO this is a key aspect of using pandas and scikit - the seamless, easy, and natural way they used to work together.  Is there a know workaround or an estimate when the inompatability will be rectified?

Comment: How is `df_train` constructed? Please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: DF train is created with lots of data mangling done in pandas,  The attribute that is having trouble is y_train.  Ytrain is a list of classes associated with the training example.  The list is used as this is a multiclass situation where each sample can below to more than one class.

Comment: '''code# build and populate y_train as integers
def get_ytrain(x):
    catlist = []
    for icat in range(len(label)):
        if label[icat] in x:
            catlist.append(icat)
    return catlist

df_train.y_train = df_train.dtu_topic_split.apply(get_ytrain)
df_holdout.y_train = df_holdout.dtu_topic_split.apply(get_ytrain)

print df_train[['dtu_docid','dtu_topic_split','y_train','predicted']][:20]
print df_holdout[['dtu_docid','dtu_topic_split','y_train','predicted']][:20]
print df_train.dtypes<blink>

Answer (score 0):

I just bumped into this too. As you point out, multiclass.py has some conservative validation:

```
# XXX: is there a way to duck-type this condition?
valid = (isinstance(y, (np.ndarray, Sequence, spmatrix))
         and not isinstance(y, string_types))
if not valid:
    raise ValueError('Expected array-like (array or non-string sequence), '
                     'got %r' % y)
```

Pandas 0.13.0 also [changed how Series is implemented](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html):

> Warning
>
> In 0.13.0 Series has internaly been refactored to no longer sub-class ndarray but instead subclass NDFrame, similarly to the rest of the pandas containers. This should be a transparent change with only very limited API implications (See the Internal Refactoring)

The [Internal Refactoring](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-0130-refactoring) note explains what to do:

> Passing a Series directly to a cython function expecting an ndarray type will no long work directly, you must pass Series.values

So in your case, I'd recommend trying this:

```
classifier.fit(df_train.dtu_content, df_train.y_train.values)
```